# Absolute value of O-U process also stationary and Markov?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Is the absolute value of an Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process stationary and Markov? Its mean and variance do not depend on time, so that makes me think that it might be stationary.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671155/measurable-function-applied-on-stationary-sequence

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it is also Markov?

Comment: Not necessarily: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2262424/a-function-of-a-markov-chain-is-necessarily-again-a-markov-chain
I don't know specifically for OU